# How to get first value from list of list in java

Tags: java

How can I get first string value from list of list.(i'm not a java expert)

```
private List<ListView> listView;

listView= List.of(firstlist(), secondlist(), thirdlist())

private List<ListView> firstlist;
private List<ListView> secondlist;
private List<ListView> thirdlist;

firstlist(){"mango", "Apple", "Ornage"}
secondlist(){"book", "pen", "pencil"}
thirdlist(){"van", "car", "lorry"}
```

Here **listview** list contains three more lists[*i.e firstlist(), secondlist(), thirdlist()*]
I need to get first value of all three lists and store it in a Arraylist. I have tried something like,

```
List listViewTitle = new ArrayList<>(listView.forEach(sublist -> sublist.getFirstValue()));
```

But it did not work out. I need to take first string from each iterator in the list of list. I need to take ***mango, book,van*** and store to the ***listViewTitle*** Arraylist

Comment: Notionally `String s = list.get(0).get(0);`

Comment: `listViewTitle.stream().map(l -> l.get(0)).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<List<String>>  list = List.of(List.of("A1","B1"),List.of("A2","B2"));

       List<String> listOnlyFirstOne  =  list
                            .stream() // create a stream
                            .map(subList -> subList.get(0)) // collect only first one of each list
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect result from map into new list
     
       listOnlyFirstOne.forEach(System.out::println); // print new list
       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> listViewTitle = new ArrayList<>();
listView.forEach(sublist -> listViewTitle.add(sublist.get(0)));
```